# Group pandas multiindex dataframe by all the indices

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like

```
Out[229]: 
                          Value
id            date             
1             1945-11-01    148
              1945-11-02    150
              1945-11-06    132
              1945-11-07    132
              1945-12-06    166
              1945-12-07    179
              1945-12-08    182
              1945-12-09    174
              1945-12-10    159
```

I'm trying something like

```
by_month = df.groupby(['id', lambda x: x.month])
```

in order to group my dataset first by id and then by month for further processing and obtain the following:

```
                          Value
id            date             
1             11            148
1             11            150
1             11            132
1             11            132
1             12            166
1             12            179
1             12            182
1             12            174
1             12            159
```

I have no clue why I'm getting

```
KeyError: u'no item named id'
```

although `df.index.names` output `FrozenList([u'id', u'date'])`.

Any hints?

Comment: @WoodyPride Both id and date. I grabbed the data from a MySQL database using [read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.sql.read_sql.html) and set `index_col = ['id', 'date']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the right of accessing `MultiIndex`, this should be right:

```
df.groupby(by=[df.index.get_level_values(0), 
           pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(1)).month]) 
#omit pd.to_datetime if already done so.
```